# Bind grid view data from existing code, current date

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to using the code below and display in GridView.
The situation is, when user click on GET CURRENT DATE TRANS, GridView will display the today date as the result. I already insert the GridView id as GridView1

```
string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlCommand command;
        string sql = null;

        connetionString = "Data Source=AXSQL;Initial Catalog=UniKL;User ID=aten;Password=pass@WORD1";
        sql = "Select * FROM [UniKL].[dbo].[BudgetPlanning_Transaction] WHERE [SubmmitedDateTime] = cast(getdate() as date)";

        GridView1.DataBind();

        connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

        connection.Open();
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Dispose();
        connection.Close();
```

Comment: So... what exactly is your question?

Comment: to show the the query (Current Date) in Grid View

Comment: What is format of you column in SQL ?

Comment: Bind data to your Grid - `GridView1.DataSource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning data source to GridView1. Please use the following code:

```
string connetionString = null;
SqlConnection connection;
SqlCommand command;
string sql = null;

connetionString = "Data Source=AXSQL;Initial Catalog=UniKL;User ID=aten;Password=pass@WORD1";
sql = "Select * FROM [UniKL].[dbo].[BudgetPlanning_Transaction] WHERE [SubmmitedDateTime] = cast(getdate() as date)";

//GridView1.DataBind();

connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
connection.Open();
command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

//Get data into a reader
SqlDataReader sr = command.ExecuteReader();
//command.ExecuteNonQuery();

//Set the datasource of GridView1
GridView1.DataSource = sr;
GridView1.DataBind();


command.Dispose();
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your column `SubmittedDateTime` is of type `DateTime` in sql so you also need to `cast` this column in `date` to match the current date like this

```
cast([SubmmitedDateTime] as Date) = cast(getdate() as date);
```

So you query will look like this

```
sql = "Select * FROM [UniKL].[dbo].[BudgetPlanning_Transaction] WHERE cast([SubmmitedDateTime] as Date) = cast(getdate() as date)";
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to change:

```
sql = "Select * FROM [UniKL].[dbo].[BudgetPlanning_Transaction] WHERE [SubmmitedDateTime] = cast(getdate() as date)";
```

to something like:

```
sql = "Select * FROM [UniKL].[dbo].[BudgetPlanning_Transaction] WHERE [SubmmitedDateTime] = " + DateTime.Now.toShortDateString();
```

or

```
sql = "Select * FROM [UniKL].[dbo].[BudgetPlanning_Transaction] WHERE [SubmmitedDateTime] = " + DateTime.Now.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```